# How to perform a basis change for QM operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

I've got a question that looks like follows:

Given two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$, with eigen vetors $|a_n\rangle$ and $|b_n\rangle$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) that constitutes a orthronormal eigen system.

If:
$$\hat{A}|a_n\rangle = a_n|a_n\rangle$$ and $$\hat{B}|b_n\rangle = b_n|b_n\rangle$$
and $$|\psi\rangle_A = \sum_n a_n|a_n\rangle$$
with coefficients  $$\alpha_n = \langle a_n|\psi\rangle$$

Give the $|\psi\rangle$ in the $\hat{B}$ representation, calculate the coefficients $\beta_n = \langle b_n | \psi\rangle$ as a function of the coefficients $a_n$ and the basis vectors $|a_n\rangle, |b_n\rangle$.

I don't really know how to proceed here. What does a basis change mean?

Comment: To answer you last question, a basis change in this case means to write $|\psi\rangle$ in the $|b_n\rangle$ basis, so it becomes $|\psi\rangle=\sum_n \beta_n |b_n\rangle$. You have to figure out what the $\beta$ coefficients are.

Comment: @Void in your third equation for the coefficients, I believe you should have $\alpha_n$ in place of $a_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\psi⟩$ is a state on the Hilbert space. You can write it in terms of a complete basis, remembering that $\sum_n |a_n⟩⟨a_n| = 1$. Inserting this "identity" in your expressions is a very useful trick that is used all the time. For example,

$|\psi⟩ = 1 |\psi⟩ = \sum_n |a_n⟩⟨a_n|\psi⟩$.

If the $|b_n⟩$ are complete too, you can write $|\psi⟩ = \sum_n |b_n⟩⟨b_n|\psi⟩ = \sum_n \beta_n|b_n⟩$ with the same method.

Note that the state $|\psi⟩$ never changes. You are only changing its basis or representation.

Inserting an "identity" again in that equation for $|\psi⟩$ expressed in term of the $|a_n⟩$, you get

$$|ψ⟩ = \sum_n ⟨a_n|ψ⟩|a_n⟩ = \sum_n a_n 1|a_n⟩ = \sum_{n, m} a_n |b_m⟩⟨b_m|a_n⟩ = \sum_m \beta_m|b_m⟩ = |ψ⟩.$$

In the last equality it is implicit that changing the representation (basis) of the state does not change the state itself. So it must be that $\beta_m = \sum_{n} a_n ⟨b_m|a_n⟩$.

Comment: Can't upvote your answer because of my low score, but thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Void ...even with low score you can accept the answer as the best one giving +15 points to the answerer. Simply click the arrow above the score of the answer, see the acceptance of low score users to answers (white check in green circle).